# Grails oauth plugin unable to install

Tags: grails, oauth

I am trying to install following plugin http://grails.org/plugin/oauth to my new Grails project but each time i try to instail i am gettin following error

```
D:\MyProjects\Grails\grails48>grails install-plugin oauth 2.1.0
| Resolving plugin oauth. Please wait...
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-oauth/tags/RELEASE_2_1_0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-oauth/tags/RELEASE_2_1_0/grails-oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.desirableobjects.co.uk/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.desirableobjects.co.uk/org/grails/plugins/oauth/2.1.0/oauth-2.1.0.zip
```

| Error resolving plugin [name:oauth, group:org.grails.plugins, version:2.1.0]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [oauth] and version [2.1.0]

Comment: are you online or offline? seems like grails can't resolve the dependencies

Comment: i am online i am inside firewall but i also set proxy. I try to check those url but there is no plugin jar found in those urls !

Comment: Note that you should not generally use `grails install-plugin` any more, use the dependency DSL instead, [as recommended in the oauth plugin documentation](http://aiten.github.com/grails-oauth-scribe/guide/quickStart.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following repo in your **BuildConfig.groovy**:

**mavenRepo "http://repo.desirableobjects.co.uk/"**